# How to assign variable value or function argument to custom_variable_class in postgresql

Tags: function, postgresql, session-variables, plpgsql

I am using a pl/pgsql function that uses `custom_variable_class`, the function code is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION can_connect("pUserId" character varying)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$DECLARE
user_id integer ;
BEGIN

SELECT users.user_serial INTO user_id
FROM public.users
WHERE users.user_id="pUserId"
;

set public.userId  to user_id  ;
 set public.companyId  to "pUserId" ;
RETURN true ;    

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
raise notice ' error %',sqlerrm ;
END ;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Now using the function

```
 select can_connect ('amr' );
 t
```

it's ok, the return value is `t` as expected.

But when trying to retrive the session variable values

```
select current_setting('public.userId') ;
the result is 
 user_id
```

Which is variable name not the value
the same thing when using the function argument

```
select current_setting('public.pUserId') ;
the result is 
pUserId
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use plpgsql [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to force the parser to interpolate the values of the variables:

```
EXECUTE 'set public.userId  to ' || quote_literal(user_id);
EXECUTE 'set public.companyId to ' || quote_literal( "pUserId");
```

As a bonus it will also work with older versions of PostgreSQL.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer fully satisfies the question, please accept it by clicking on the check mark (read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for how/why)

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to [`SET`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set.html) only PostgreSQL's configuration parameters this way.

On PostgreSQL 9.1 I have the following output:

```sql
SET user_id TO bbb;
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "user_id"
```

As PostgreSQL has no packages, the best way to keep state is to use [temporary tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-porting.html).

Comment: The code uses [custom_variable_classes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-custom.html). It assumes that postgresql.conf contains a line like `custom_variable_classes = 'public'`

Comment: Thank you vyegorov for your quick response
I have already set the custom_variable_classes in the configuration file